# Getting this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setMaxNumberPointsPerLink' of null

Tags: reactjs, redux, diagram

I'm using [this](https://github.com/projectstorm/react-diagrams/) library for diagrams.

I've my code in componentWillMount like so,

```
class FlowDiagramEngine extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.flowJson = this.props.flowDiagramData;
    this.state = {};
}
componentWillMount() {
    console.log("this.flowJson :"+this.flowJson); // this is empty
    var engine = ...
    engine.setDiagramModel(model);
    .... all code to construct diagram
    this.setState({engine: engine});
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <FlowDiagramWidget className="srd-demo-canvas" {...this.state} />   
        </div>
    )
}

}
```

*FlowDiagramWidget*

```
class FlowDiagramWidget extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Grid container
                    justify="space-between"
                    alignItems="center">

                  <DiagramWidget className="srd-demo-canvas" diagramEngine={this.props.engine} />   
                </Grid>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default FlowDiagramWidget
```

I want my Redux props in componentWillMount but during exection of the lifecycle method componentWillMount the async prop is empty. The redux props is properly initialized in the constructor.

Whenever I change componentWillMount to componentDidMount I get the following error. Why does this likely happen?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setMaxNumberPointsPerLink' of null
    at DiagramWidget.render (main.js:1)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (ReactCompositeComponent.js:796)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:819)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:359)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:255)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:43)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:234)
    at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (ReactDOMComponent.js:701)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountComponent (ReactDOMComponent.js:520)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:43)
```

Edit: I have this in the parent container:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
     flowDiagramData: state.appReducer.flowDiagramData
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to show more of the component code?

Comment: Added some more code.

Comment: Are you using `mapStateToProps`? to connect the component to the redux store?

Comment: Where do you access setMaxNumberPointsPerLink in your code. Please share that code. One thing is before accessing this property you need to check whether it is null or not only then access it using conditional check like setMaxNumberPointsPerLink && setMaxNumberPointsPerLink . If you can share the code will be able to help you right fix

Comment: @PaulMcloughlin Edited my post to show how container looks like.

Comment: @Think-Twice I'm not calling this method in my code.

Comment: Can you share DiagramWidget component code? The issue is from this component render so share the code of it. Please don’t share piece by piece share the full code for quick resolution and time save for you and for others as well

Comment: @Think-Twice As the child component just has a one liner `render()` thought it wouldn't matter much. Anyways I have added it.

Comment: I want to see DiagramWidget but not FlowDiagramWidget

Comment: @Think-Twice That is a library component. `import { DiagramWidget } from 'storm-react-diagrams';`

Comment: Ok can you try this in your FlowDiagramWidget {this.props.engine && <DiagramWidget className="srd-demo-canvas" diagramEngine={this.props.engine} /> }

Comment: Seems to work with componentDidMount. Whats the reason behind that? However this property `this.flowJson` initialized in constructor is empty in `componentDidMount`. Any way to fix that? Please promote this to the answer in that case.